# Is something similar to TypeScript's non null assertion operator in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[Non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)

Example:

```
function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
    validateEntity(e);
    let s = e!.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly similar, but you can add [type casting expression](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/) before the line with let with something like this:

```
function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
    validateEntity(e);
    (e: Entity);
    let s = e.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
}
```

But it will not help you to not dun in the error is e is null, so I think using `if` is the best shoot here:

```
function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
    validateEntity(e);
    if (e) {
        let s = e!.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
    }
}
```